# Dataflow - Profiles : How to check failed products in import all product

Tags: magento-1.7, import, dataflow

I have created CSV file and run profile. Some products failed due to image not found issue. I want to find out which products have failed in the process. 
Are there anyway to echo sku for failed products?
Do these kind of errors log in the system?

EDIT

I could find a way to find failed products using **firebug**. But it's not a good solution for this. Is there anyone know to check this, highly appreciate.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

As I know there is no configuration to turn debug on
But you can set it manually in

> Mage_ImportExport_Model_Abstract

Set property **$_debugMode**

> protected $_debugMode = true;